# Configure NFS share for Kubernetes 1.5 on Atomic Host: Permission Denied

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm using two VMs with Atomic Host (1 Master, 1 Node; Centos Image). I want to use NFS shares from another VM (Ubuntu Server 16.04) as persistent volumes for my pods. I can mount them manually and in Kubernetes (Version 1.5.2) the persistent volumes are successfully created and bound to my PVCs. Also they are mounted in my pods. **But when I try to write or even read from the corresponding folder inside the pod, I get the error `Permission denied`.** From my research I think, the problem lies within the folders permission/owner/group on my NFS Host.

My exports file on the Ubuntu VM (`/etc/exports`) has 10 shares with the following pattern (The two IPs are the IPs of my Atomic Host Master and Node):

```
/home/user/pv/pv01   192.168.99.101(rw,insecure,async,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash) 192.168.99.102(rw,insecure,async,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
```

In the image for my pods I create a new user named `guestbook`, so that the container doesn't use a privileged user, as this insecure. I read many post like [this one](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/write-permission-for-users-on-nfs-folder-852800/), that state, you have to set the permissions to world-writable or using the same UID and GID for the shared folders. So in my Dockerfile I create the `guestbook` user with the UID `1003` and a group with the same name and GID `1003`:

```
RUN groupadd -r guestbook -g 1003 && useradd -u 1003 -r -g 1003 guestbook
```

On my NFS Host I also have a user named `guestbook` with UID `1003` as a member of the group `nfs` with GID `1003`. The permissions of the shared folders (with `ls -l`) are as following:

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 guestbook nfs 4096 Feb 19 11:23 pv01
```

(world writable, owner guestbook, group nfs). In my Pod I can see the permissions of the mounted folder `/data` (again with `ls -l`) as:

```
drwxrwxrwx. 2 guestbook guestbook 4096 Feb 9 13:37 data
```

The persistent Volumes are created with an YAML file with the pattern:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv01
  annotations:
    pv.beta.kubernetes.io/gid: "1003"
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 200Mi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
  nfs:
    path: /home/user/pv/pv01
    server: 192.168.99.104
```

The Pod is created with this YAML file:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: get-started
spec:
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: get-started
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: get-started
        image: docker.io/cebberg/get-started:custom5
        ports:
        - containerPort: 2525
        env:
        - name: GET_HOSTS_FROM
          value: dns
        - name: REDIS_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: redis
              key: database-password
        volumeMounts:
        - name: log-storage
          mountPath: "/data/"
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        securityContext:
          privileged: false
      volumes:
      - name: log-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: get-started
      restartPolicy: Always
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
```

And the PVC with YAML file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: get-started
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Mi
```

I tried different configuration for the owner/group of the folders. If I use my normal user (which is the same on all systems) as owner and group, I can mount manually and read and write in the folder. But I don't want to use my normal user, but use another user (and especially not a privileged user).

**What permissions do I have to set, so that the user I create in my Pod can write to the NFS volume?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem:
By accident I found log entries, that appear everytime I try to access the NFS volumes from my pods. They say, that SELinux has blocked the access to the folder because of different security context.

To resolve the issue, I simply had to turn on the corresponding SELinux boolean `virt_use_nfs` with the command

```
setsebool virt_use_nfs on
```

This has to be done on all nodes to make it work correctly.

EDIT:
I remembered, that I now use `sec=sys` as mount option in `/etc/exports`. This provides access controll based on UID and GID of the user creating a file (which seems to be the default). If you use `sec=none` you also have to turn on the SELinux boolean `nfsd_anon_write`, so that the user `nfsnobody` has the permission to create files.